# How to use Office.StartupBehavior.load inside a taskpane add-in?

Tags: office-js

According to [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/run-code-on-document-open), it is possible to set up code to run as soon as the document is opened:

> You can configure your Office Add-in to load and run code as soon as the document is opened. This is useful if you need to register event handlers, pre-load data for the task pane, synchronize UI, or perform other tasks before the add-in is visible.
>
> The following code configures your add-in to load and start running when the document is opened.
>
> `Office.addin.setStartupBehavior(Office.StartupBehavior.load);`

This is exactly what I'm planning to do: load translations for the add-in based on the document content language before the user opens the taskpane to decrease its loading time.

However, the docs aren't explicit on where the above code should be placed. Is it on `taskpane.js` (or whatever the entrypoint for my code is in taskpane.html)?

Also, the docs note that the method `setStartupBehavior` is asynchronous. Is awaiting its resolution relevant for anything?

And lastly, this method call clearly depends on the `Office` global. Must I place it after initialization (`Office.onReady`/`Office.initialize`) or is it allowed immediately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this sample for an example of how to use the API: [excel-shared-runtime-scenario](https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP-OfficeAddins/tree/3ce0e1b74152dbbe8306a091696bc4455c04c0a1/Samples/excel-shared-runtime-scenario).

It cannot be called before `Office.onReady`/`Office.initialize`, but it can be called inside them. However, the effect doesn't happen until the next time the document opens and there is no need to call it every time the document is opened. Once it is called with the `load` parameter, then the code will run whenever the document opens, unless/until it is (re)called with `none`.

Since the function has no effect until the next time the document opens, I don't see any point to awaiting it.